# Python Selenium - How to find specific text inside span

Tags: python, html, selenium

Trying to locate specific text that is inside span element, which will be used as the basis for a successful test but not getting it to work. Can someone help?
I want to retrieve the text again inside span as my basis for demonstrating that the update I am looking for was done (earlier on in the code I post that update text to the record)

My code is as follows -

```
# Check for the update
    check_work_info = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*/span[contains(text(),'AUTOMATED TESTING INCIDENT CREATE 2018-10-18')]")
    print(check_work_info)
```

The error raised is -

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
>   locate element: //*/span[contains(text(),'AUTOMATED TESTING INCIDENT
>   CREATE 2018-10-18')]

HTML snippet of source -

```
<div class="sn-card-component sn-card-component_summary sn-card-component_summary_spacing ng-scope" ng-repeat="journal in ::entry.entries.journal">
    <div class="sn-widget sn-widget-textblock state-expanded" ng-class="{ 'state-expanded': journal.showMore || expandEntries }">
        <span class="sn-widget-textblock-body sn-widget-textblock-body_formatted ng-binding" ng-bind-html="parseSpecial(journal.new_value)">AUTOMATED TESTING INCIDENT UPDATE 2018-10-18</span>
        <!-- ngIf: ::journal.is_truncated -->
    </div>
    <!-- ngIf: ::journal.new_value.length > 200 -->
    <!-- ngIf: ::journal.new_value.length > 200 -->
</div>
<div class="sn-widget sn-widget-textblock state-expanded" ng-class="{ 'state-expanded': journal.showMore || expandEntries }">
    <span class="sn-widget-textblock-body sn-widget-textblock-body_formatted ng-binding" ng-bind-html="parseSpecial(journal.new_value)">AUTOMATED TESTING INCIDENT UPDATE 2018-10-18</span>
    <!-- ngIf: ::journal.is_truncated --></div>
    <span class="sn-widget-textblock-body sn-widget-textblock-body_formatted ng-binding" ng-bind-html="parseSpecial(journal.new_value)">AUTOMATED TESTING INCIDENT UPDATE 2018-10-18</span>
```

Comment: Text seem to be `"AUTOMATED TESTING INCIDENT UPDATE 2018-10-18"`, but not `"AUTOMATED TESTING INCIDENT CREATE 2018-10-18"`

Comment: You are trying to locate the element AFTER you have performed the necessary action for it to change to update? Did you try adding some waits?

Comment: Yes, sorry I realized the text was different just after I posed the question. Anyways this works check_work_info = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*/span[contains(text(),'AUTOMATED TESTING INCIDENT UPDATE 2018-10-18')]")   and then .. print(check_work_info.text) to capture the text again

Answer (score 0):

//*/span[contains(text(),'AUTOMATED')]